# meaing of maxlen in INFORMATION_SCHEMA CHARACTER_SETS Table of MySQL

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

From mysql official website:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/character-sets-table.html

YOu will see this table definition.

Can anybody here tell what does 'maxlen' mean?  max length of bytes for character encoding?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-character-set.html):

> The Maxlen column shows the maximum number of bytes required to store one character.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that all the `maxlen` values fall between 1 and 4, and that the `ascii` character set has `maxlen=1`, I'd say it's the maximum length *in bytes* for a character in the character set.

More proof: `UTF8` has `maxlen=3` and `UTF16` has `maxlen=4`.

Remember that the `maxlen` is just that - a maximum. Some `UTF16` characters will be less than 4 bytes.